# How to setup a socket connection when you don't know the URL in advance?

Tags: nginx, socket.io, network-programming, localhost

I'm trying to setup a Docker container with NGINX and NuxtJS that will be hosted in on AWS EBS. I might setup DNS for it later, but as of right now I won't know the URL in advance. Is there anyway to tell NGINX/socket.io to use address of the machine where the container is running?

I've been using 'localhost' as a placeholder value, which works fine in development on my local machine. But when hosted on EBS the app is still trying to connect to my machine on the socket's port.

**CURRENT SETTINGS**

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://nuxt:3000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

socket.io (this is from a module but you can see the url is set to localhost)

```
io: {
        sockets: [{     
            default: true,
            name: 'mainSocket',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000'
        }],
    },
```

Docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this socket code running in a web browser? Or where?

Comment: The socket code is part of nuxt.config.js which I believe runs in the browser as part of NuxtJS.

Comment: then "this current host" is incorrect because "this host" would be the host where the browser is running. You could try using the data in [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to see what is in the browser's address bar, then use that to connect.

Comment: Is there any way to get the window.location data from an environment variable? Or some other way to devise it from the application? I suppose I could setup an AWS EBS app, check the URL, and then modify the code and host the application...

Comment: On the server you could look at the HTTP Host header which shows what the browser thinks your server is called

Comment: For the module I'm using, I discovered in the docs that if you simply do not specify a URL for the socket it will default to 'window.location'. So the solution was to just remove that line from the socket code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per user253751's comments the window.location contains data about the URL for the application. In the module I was using this value was easily accessible. That might not always be the case.